# Error Access Denied Reload for desktopbrowser environment in MFS 7.1

Tags: android, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-studio

I made simple application. Added android and desktopbrowser environments. Android app works fine.

While preview desktopbrowser environment getting Error Access Denied Reload dialog box infinite times.

Made below two changes in "worklight.properties" file.

`mfp.session.independent=false`

`mfp.attrStore.type=HttpSession`

Tried with restarting server and eclipse as well.

Code to reproduce below:

```
function wlCommonInit(){

    WL.Client.connect({
                onSuccess: onConnectSuccess,
                onFailure: onConnectFailure
            });

}

function onConnectSuccess(){
    alert("Connected to Server");
    WL.Client.checkForDirectUpdate();

}

function onConnectFailure(){
    alert("Connection Failure");
}

$("p").click(function(){
    alert("Paragraph Clicked");
    getData();
});

function loadFeedsSuccess(result){
    invocationResult = result.invocationResult;
   alert(JSON.stringify(invocationResult.firstName));
   alert(JSON.stringify(invocationResult.lastName));
}

function loadFeedsFailure(error){
   console.log("Feed retrieve failure");
   alert(JSON.stringify(error));
   alert("Feed retrieve failure");
}


function getData() {
    var invocationData = {
            adapter : 'Test',
            procedure : 'getAdapter',
            parameters : []
        };

    WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData,{
        onSuccess :  loadFeedsSuccess,
        onFailure : loadFeedsFailure,
    });
}
```

Comment: When you use the chrome inspector do you see any issues in the javascript console?

Comment: FWIW, I was able to copy/paste the above code into a freshly created MFP 7.1 hybrid app with a desktop browser environment (by putting it in main.js), made the indicated changes to worklight.properties, and in my environment it works correctly.  It might be interesting to see what's in the development server logs (under your Eclipse workspace directory in "MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/logs).

Comment: Console am getting as : wlclient init started
before: initOptions.onSuccess
Request [/Test/apps/services/api/Test/desktopbrowser/init]
 Application details header: {"applicationDetails":{"platformVersion":"7.1.0.0","nativeVersion":""}}WL.Logger.__log @ 
 after: initOptions.onSuccess
 wlclient init success
http://vishalps-macbook-pro.local:10080/Test/apps/services/api/Test/desktopbrowser/init Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: can you change your host name to your actual ip address and test again?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce this.

1. Created a new project in IBM MobileFirst Platform Studio 7.1.0.00-20160321-2138
2. In server\conf\worklight.properties I have set `mfp.attrStore.type=HttpSession` and `mfp.session.independent=false`
3. Added the Mobile Web environment
4. Added code for `WL.Client.connect()` in main.js -> `wlCommonInit()`
5. Run As -> Run on MobileFirst Development Server
6. Preview in Console

I got a dialog showing "success" (the success callback of `onSuccess`).

Comment: Thank you Idan. Again I tried same. This time I added Mobile Web environment along with desktopbrowser. But still getting same error in both environments. Am using IBM MobileFirst Platform Studio 7.1.0.00-20160401-2103 which is available in eclipse market place. Please let me whether am I working in wrong version of Mobile First Studio.